# Для того(,) чтобы

Tags: пунктуация

Ведь ранее(,) для того(,) чтобы приехать в эту страну, требовалась виза.

Задумалась, где именно необходимо поставить запятую. Или верны оба варианта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ситуации с союзом **для того(,) чтобы** могут быть разные. В данном случае мне кажется, что  запятая внутри союза стоять не будет и конечная расстановка такая:

> Ведь ранее, для того чтобы приехать в эту страну, требовалась виза.

См. [грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach3/)