# Нужна ли запятая внутри союза "для того чтобы"?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

***Для того(,) чтобы безопасно перевезти пианино, нужно, во-первых, завернуть пианино в одеяло для грузоперевозок и обмотать его строительным скотчем.***

Если нет, то объясните доходчиво — почему?

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался, см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/22786/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможны.

[Розенталь. § 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138)

В зависимости от смысла и интонации, логического подчеркивания придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, наличия в предложении определенных лексических элементов и других условий сложный союз может расчленяться на две части: первая входит в состав главной части как соотносительное слово, а вторая выступает в роли союза.

1) В начале предложения составные союзы обычно не расчленяются (нейтральная ситуация): Для того чтобы безопасно перевезти пианино, нужно, во-первых, завернуть пианино в одеяло для грузоперевозок и обмотать его строительным скотчем.

2) При расчленении союза ПОДЧЕРКИВАЕТСЯ ЗНАЧИМОСТЬ  выделенной запятыми придаточной части: Для того, чтобы безопасно перевезти пианино, нужно, во-первых, завернуть пианино в одеяло для грузоперевозок и обмотать его строительным скотчем.

Answer (score 3):

Придаточная часть в сложноподчиненном предложении может присоединяться к главной с помощью ***составных*** (из нескольких слов) ***подчинительных союзов***, например:
*ввиду того что, вместо того чтобы, в случае если, несмотря на то что, **для того чтобы**, перед тем как, потому что, прежде чем* и др.
Пунктуационная трудность заключается в том, что такие союзы могут **целиком** входить в придаточную часть или же **расчленяться** (в нашем случае элемент "для того" будет отдельным указательным словом — предлогом с местоимением).

В предложении нет причин для расчленения союза:
[***Пунктуация в конструкциях с составными подчинительными союзами***](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/606/%E2%86%91%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_3).

Составной подчинительный союз расчленяется и запятая ставится между частями союза, если выполняется хотя бы одно из следующих условий:
1) перед составным союзом имеется отрицание "не";
2) перед составным союзом есть усилительные, ограничительные и другие частицы, вводные слова, наречия;
3) первая часть составного союза входит в ряд однородных членов предложения или параллельных конструкций;
4) автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение.

Если следовать "букве правил" и если бы мне пришлось  выбирать, я бы не стала "делить" союз:
***Для того чтобы*** безопасно перевезти пианино, нужно, во-первых, завернуть пианино в одеяло для грузоперевозок и обмотать его строительным скотчем.